# PrintWriter#println() throws a NullPointerException in the Thread

Tags: android, exception, android-intent, android-service

I am trying to send a `String` message with `PrintWriter#println(message)` but it throws an exception as soon as I call the thread.
I don't know from where this message is coming from. I checked if the message is `null` but it is not the case.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import android.util.Log;

public class Send_Client implements Runnable {
    private PrintWriter out;
    private String message=null;

    public Send_Client(PrintWriter out,String message) {
        this.out=out;
        this.message=message;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // the message is different from null
        // Problem to resolve
        out.println(message);
        out.flush();
        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "The message has been sent from Send_Client");
    }
}
```

And here is where I call the thread

```
    public class ClientDataService extends IntentService {
private static Socket socket=null;
private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 5000;

public static final String ACTION_CLIENT="Action_Client";
public static final String EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_PORT = "go_port";
public static final String EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_ADDRESS = "go_host";
String message=null;
private BufferedReader in=null;
public PrintWriter out=null;
/** Command to the service to receive a message */
static final int MSG_CLIENT = 2;

public ClientDataService(String name) {
    super(name);

}
public ClientDataService() {
    super("ClientDataService");
    }
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_CLIENT)) {
        int port = intent.getExtras().getInt(EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_PORT);
        String host=  intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_ADDRESS);
            try{
                Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "ask for connection to the server");
                socket=new Socket();
                socket.bind(null);
                socket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(host, port)), SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
                Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "connection socket has been established");

                try{
                    in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    out= new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                    Thread t1=new Thread(new Receive_Client(in));
                    t1.start();

                }catch(IOException e){
                    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "the client disconnect");

            } 

            }catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "impossible to connect to the host"+socket.getLocalSocketAddress());
            }catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "No Server Listening the port"+socket.getLocalPort());
            }

    }
      }
public PrintWriter getOutputstream(){
    return out;
}

 /**
     * Handler of incoming messages from UI Thread.
      */
     class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
    ClientDataService mservice;
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_CLIENT:
                 mservice=new ClientDataService();
                Log.d(MainActivity.TAG,"CDS has received the following message to send to the server"+(String)msg.obj);
                Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Get the Out value"+mservice.getOutputstream().toString());
                Thread t2= new Thread(new Send_Client(mservice.getOutputstream(),(String)msg.obj));
                t2.start();
                break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
   }

   /**
   * Target we publish for clients to send messages to IncomingHandler.
   */
   final Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());

   /**
    * When binding to the service, we return an interface to our messenger
   * for sending messages to the service.
    */
   @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "binding client", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return mMessenger.getBinder();
  }

  }
```

Comment: Is `out` non-null too?

Comment: Where exactly is the NPE thrown? In the `out.println(message)` line?

Comment: The only possibility of the NPE getting thrown in that line is when `out` is `null`. So check whether that is the case.

Comment: Yes, i just checked and in fact the problem is coming from out.

Comment: @Veger ,I just modified the post. Actually i want to use "out" created in the onhandleIntent. But when i try to use this "out" the app crash. Do you have any idea about how i can solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post this as an answer as it is a bit long for a comment (even though I cannot provide a complete/direct solution).

The problem occurs because:

1. `out` is not yet set in `ClientDataService` when you created its object in `IncomingHandler`
2. so `mservice.getOutputstream()` return `null`
3. which you use in `Send_Client`.

You are misusing the `ServerIntent`, by directly creating a derived object from it using `new ClientDataService()`.

Instead you need to start a services as follows, acording to the [Android Service documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#StartingAService):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelloService.class);
startService(intent);
```

So I guess you need to read more about android services (lots of information in the documentation that looks important to me) in order to properly use them in your application.

Comment: I think i find the problem, yes in fact i tried this solution because when using out alone, it was returning null.
Since the incoming handler is an inner class to ClientDataService i just put ClientDataService.this.out and normally it should work without using any instance of new ClientDataService(). Thanks a lot for your help @Veger